# Sand Simulation Renders Slowly in Pyglet

Tags: python, pyglet

I was following the latest coding challenge by The Coding Train. In his video, using p5.js, he builds a falling sand simulator, I decided to try the challenge using pyglet.

I did some tests, but I noticed that my program renders very slowly compared to [his](https://editor.p5js.org/codingtrain/sketches/AoH40T6fV). I know I'm re-drawing the grid at every frame, but my code's logic is similar to The Coding Train's one and he doesn't experience the same issue.

I'm sure there's a better way to handle the sand falling, but since I just started learning pyglet I'm not sure how to proceed.

Here's the code:

```py
import random
import math
# pyglet libraries
import pyglet
from pyglet import shapes
from pyglet.window import mouse

SCREEN_WIDTH = 400
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 400
SAND_SIZE = 10

def make2DArray(rows, cols):
    arr = [[0 for y in range(cols)] for x in range(rows)]
    for row in range(rows):
        for col in range(cols):
            arr[row][col] = 0
    return arr


window = pyglet.window.Window(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)

rows = int(SCREEN_WIDTH / SAND_SIZE)
cols = int(SCREEN_HEIGHT / SAND_SIZE)
grid = make2DArray(rows, cols)
grid[30][20] = 1


@window.event
def on_mouse_drag(x, y, dx, dy, buttons, modifiers):
    row = math.floor(x / SAND_SIZE)
    col = math.floor(y / SAND_SIZE)
    grid[row][col] = 1


@window.event
def on_draw():
    global grid

    for row in range(rows):
        for col in range(cols):
            if grid[row][col] == 0:
                rectangle = shapes.Rectangle(row*10, col*10, 10, 10, color=(0, 0, 0))
            else:
                rectangle = shapes.Rectangle(row*10, col*10, 10, 10, color=(255, 255, 255))
            rectangle.draw()
    # Generating New State
    next_state_grid = make2DArray(rows, cols)
    for row in range(rows):
        for col in range(cols):
            current_state = grid[row][col]
            if current_state == 1:
                below = grid[row][col - 1]
                if below == 0 and col != 0:
                    next_state_grid[row][col - 1] = 1
                else:
                    next_state_grid[row][col] = 1
    grid = next_state_grid


pyglet.app.run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pyglet uses hardware acceleration (OpenGL) to draw its images. When you call `rectangle.draw()`, you're making a draw call to the GPU which is *very* slow. You're expected to reduce draw calls as much as possible as communication between the CPU and GPU is generally what takes time.

The [documentation](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/shapes.html#pyglet.shapes.ShapeBase.draw) explicitly discourages you from using this function and instead suggests using **batches**.

Batches will collect everything you want to draw and then optimize the amount of draw calls. Here's the example from the documentation where they add all shapes to a [batch](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/graphics/index.html#pyglet.graphics.Batch) and use `batch.draw()`:

```py
import pyglet
from pyglet import shapes

window = pyglet.window.Window(960, 540)
batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()

circle = shapes.Circle(700, 150, 100, color=(50, 225, 30), batch=batch)
square = shapes.Rectangle(200, 200, 200, 200, color=(55, 55, 255), batch=batch)
rectangle = shapes.Rectangle(250, 300, 400, 200, color=(255, 22, 20), batch=batch)
rectangle.opacity = 128
rectangle.rotation = 33
line = shapes.Line(100, 100, 100, 200, width=19, batch=batch)
line2 = shapes.Line(150, 150, 444, 111, width=4, color=(200, 20, 20), batch=batch)
star = shapes.Star(800, 400, 60, 40, num_spikes=20, color=(255, 255, 0), batch=batch)

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    batch.draw()

pyglet.app.run()
```